# Python string corrompida com caractere \

Tags: python, string, python-3.x, diretório, concatenação-de-string

Eu tenho um programa que cria para seu funcionamento outro programa no computador do usuário. Em um trecho, eu defino o diretório a que o novo programa será destinado como

```
 diret = "C:\\Users\\" + d_user
```

em que d_user é o resto do diretório. Porém ao ser criado e executado, o string é convertido para

```
'C:\Users\'
```

com uma barra apenas, o que suscita

```
SyntaxError: EOL while scanning string literal
```

pois a string não é fechada no segundo ['].

Como posso prevenir que isso ocorra a fim de que meu código seja executado plenamente?

**EDIT:**

O código dentro do código principal, que será criado, está disponível em https://ideone.com/KTAQxf das linhas 4 a 24; as demais são apenas contexto do código principal. O erro acontece com a linha 10.

Comment: Pode dar um exemplo completo que falha? Não consigo reproduzir o erro.

Comment: @PedrovonHertwig Atualizei, agradeço de antemão qualquer ajuda.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A linha

```
diret = "C:\\Users\\" + d_user
```

está correta. O que acontece é que o `\` é um caracter de escape; quer dizer, quando você precisa por exemplo usar aspas sem terminar a string, você pode fazer

```
s = "aspas: \" <- interpretado como aspas sem fechar a string"
```

Assim, ele é interpretado de forma especial e ele mesmo também precisa ser escapado com `\`. Quando se quer botar um caracter `\` na string, é necessário usar `\\` (o primeiro "escapa" o segundo e o segundo é interpretado literalmente).

O que você escreve em um arquivo novo está escapado, mas portanto resulta em escrever só um `\` por vez. Quando o segundo arquivo é lido, só há um `\` e ele escapa as aspas duplas de fim da string.

Para resolver seu problema, há duas soluções possíveis. A primeira é dobrar as barras no `key_file.write`:

```
...
diret = "C:\\\\Users\\\\" + d_user
...
```

E a segunda e talvez mais elegante é usar uma string bruta, ou raw, prefixando ela com `r`. Assim, o `\` é tratado como um caracter normal.

```
key_file.write(r'''
    import sys
    [...]
    input()''')
```